# Why is the side effect of mutating list bad in the quicksort algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm, list, quicksort

In the following link http://en.literateprograms.org/Quicksort_%28Python%29 the following 
claim is made. We make use of the pop operation to remove our chosen pivot. This has the unfortunate side effect of mutating the original list that was passed to the sort function. Why is it an unfortunate side effect? Even when I call qsort function directly below, I get the sorted list as an output given that we have the return statement.

```
from random import randrange       
def qsort1a(list):
    """
    Quicksort using list comprehensions and randomized pivot
    >>> qsort1a<<docstring test numeric input>>
    <<docstring test numeric output>>
    >>> qsort1a<<docstring test string input>>
    <<docstring test string output>>
    """
    def qsort(list):
        if list == []: 
            return []
        else:
            pivot = list.pop(randrange(len(list)))
            lesser = qsort([l for l in list if l < pivot])
            greater = qsort([l for l in list if l >= pivot])
            return lesser + [pivot] + greater
    return qsort(list[:])
```

Comment: A quick-fix for this function : http://ideone.com/G9Yjti

Comment: I think the side effect is to avoid the change of the original list using `pop`, you have to pass a copy, and this is not memory efficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is bad because you are getting a new list anyway.  Why have two copies of the same list?  What if you want to keep using the original unsorted list somewhere.  Functions that have a return value probably should not mutate their arguments.

EDIT: I'll provide an example why mutating arguments can be confusing.  In c++.

Add trivial add funciton.

```
int add(int a, int b)
{
   a += b;
   return a;
}

int addBad(int &a, int &b)
{
   a += b;
   return a;
}

for(int i=0;i<10;++i)
{
   for(int j=0;j<10;++j)
   {
      cout << add(i,j) << endl;
   }
}

for(int i=0;i<10;++i)
{
   for(int j=0;j<10;++j)
   {
      cout << addBad(i,j) << endl;
   }
}
```

Both these look so similar if the programmer doesn't know what is happening in `add` and `addBad`.  And the implementations of `add` and `addBad` can be interchanged and the code will still compile.  Python can be similar because passing by reference seems to happen a lot and without explicit declaration of it.

Comment: You mean you shouldn't mutate the argument that you return

Comment: @aaronman You really shouldn't mutate any argument you receive unless the semantics of doing so are clear to the user. One typical way to do this is to return None -- this makes it obvious that your function is a mutator rather than a pipe.

Answer (score 5):

You have, in effect, "fixed the bad thing" by defining your `qsort1a` as a wrapper around the inner `qsort`.  Your wrapper makes a copy of the original list, using the slice operator:

```
return qsort(list[:])
```

If you remove the copy operation, making the last line read:

```
return qsort(list)
```

and then run this, you can see why it's "bad":

```
>>> from qsort1a import qsort1a
>>> orig = [3, 17, 4, 0, 2]
>>> qsort1a(orig)
[0, 2, 3, 4, 17]
>>> orig
[3, 17, 4, 2]
>>>
```

The output is still sorted, but the original list `orig` has changed.

(Also, as others noted, it's generally unwise to re-use names like `list` as local variables, since it makes it unnecessarily difficult to access Python's built-in `list` function.)

Comment: YEs I know, I just copied the code from the website. I did not use the variable 'list' in my code.

Answer (score 2):

Everything works fine since your just give a copy of the argument. The bad thing is to keep the implementation simple, using `pop` and list comprehension, you need to pass several copies of original list. This is not as memory efficient as sort in place.

By the way, don't use `list` as a variable name.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, you want to sort a list in-place.  Sometimes, you need a sorted *copy* of a list (e.g., if you also want to preserve the original unsorted order).  So, the Python standard library lets you write both `lst.sort()` and `sorted(lst)`.

But it's unusual in Python for a function to both mutate its argument *and* return a value.  The more common convention is [Command-Query Separation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation), in which mutator functions return `None`.  For example, in the `list` class, the `append`, `clear`, `extend`, `remove`, `reverse`, and `sort` methods, that add, remove, or reorder the items in the list, all return `None`.

The `pop` method is an exception, a case of [practicality beats purity](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/).